# how to determine onChange event triggered by browser

Tags: javascript, forms, browser, onchange

**Situation:** I have a form for the user to change their profile.

The form has input fields with event listeners attached for the `onchange` event so I can tell if the user has made any changes to the form. One of those fields is a password field.

In the case where the browser is set to remember passwords, when the form loads, it fills in the password field and triggers my listener.

**Workaround:**

I have set a timeout to reset my dataChanged flag after the page loads. Not very elegant. It seems that crawling the event.callee.caller stack is not recommended, non-standard, and unlikely to distinguish user- from browser-initiated events.

**Question:**

Is there a way I can determine events triggered by the user interaction (and javascript) only?

I don't want to *cancel* the event though, I just want to *ignore* it.

**Clarification on choice of event:**

This code is in our form-handling js library used throughout numerous applications. We need to know if the field has actually changed its contents so we can warn the user on leaving the form that data has not been saved. It is also used to trigger recalculation of other co-dependent fields.

Using onkeyup/onkeypress will trigger when the user presses non-editing keys like Tab, cursor-arrow, Shift etc. We want to avoid having to store the contents as loaded, and compare that to the content after onkeyup to determine whether the contents have actually changed.

Browsers also trap conditions where the user edits the field, changes their mind and presses ESC or CTRL-Z - onchange is not triggered. Event onkeypress fires many times during that process.

Therefore we would want to stick to onchange as the event of choice since it designed for our purpose - fire when content actually changes, once only when user exits the field.

Comment: Why not use `keypress`, `keydown`,  `keyup`, or `blur` event? This is actual user actions and these events shouldn't be fired by the browser's autocomplete.

Comment: Clarification added to the question to explain why we want to use onchange. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can set autocomplete="off" on the username and/or password field to stop the browser from auto-filling them

Comment: Good idea, but I don't want to force them to enter the password. Letting the browser fill in the password is okay by me.

Comment: This is not reliable, as some browsers intentionally ignore `autocomplete=off`: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/topic/chromium-dev/zhhj7hCip5c/discussion

Comment: Yes @MarounBaydoun, they can indeed change their password. It is a form for them to change their "Profile"; name, usercode, password etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `onkeyup` to handle this:

1. While loading your window you don't need to attach events to the
   `onchange` of the fields so they can be autofilled by the browser.
2. And `onkeyup` of a field you will attach the event to its `onchange` so
   the `onchange` event will only fire only if the user really changed
   this field value.

For example:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="password" onkeyup="giveOnchangeEvent(this)"/>
```

**JS:**

```
 function giveOnchangeEvent(input) {
    input.onchange = function() {
      //give the actions you need to do here
    }
 }
```

And that should do the trick.

## EDIT:

To solve all the problems stated in your EDIT, you can use `onfocus` instead of `onkeyup` and append the `onchange` listener only and only if the `input` is focused by the user, and this way the browser auto filling actions will not count anymore.

Just change the `onkeyup` with `onfocus` in your input:

```
<input type="password" onfocus="giveOnchangeEvent(this)"/>
```

**Note:**

This approach avoids **only** the first `onchange` (of the browser) which is fired when the window loads.

Comment: Not a bad idea. I added more detail to the question as to why I would rather use onchange.

Comment: @PeterBrand Just change the `onkeyup` with `onfocus` in your input and all the problems will be solved, you can see it in my EDIT.